# Как сделать линию которая покаэет кто победил

Tags: javascript, html, css

делаю игру крестики нолики, логика работает но не могу сделать так, что когда кто то из игроков достигает 3х "Х" или "О", что бы там отображалась линия.

как это сделать пишу на тайпскрипте

вот этот код проверяет кто победил

```
    checkWinConditionPc(){
  const bool = this.arrayComputer[0];
  this.winArray.forEach(array => {

    const field1 = array[0];
    const field2 = array[1];
    const field3 = array[2];

    if (this.arrayComputer[array[0]] && this.arrayComputer[array[1]] && this.arrayComputer[array[2]]){
      console.log("Computerwin")
      alert(this.player2 + " WON");
      setTimeout(()=>{this.reload()}, 1000);
    }

  })
}

checkWinCondition() {
  const bool = this.arrayPlayer[0];

  this.winArray.forEach(array => {
    // [0, 1, 2]
    const feld1 = array[0];
    const feld2 = array[1];
    const feld3 = array[2];

    // if (false & 1 & 2)
    if (this.arrayPlayer[array[0]] && this.arrayPlayer[array[1]] && this.arrayPlayer[array[2]]) {
      console.log("Playerwin")
      this.dis.fill(true);
      alert(this.player + " WON")
     setTimeout(()=>{this.reload()}, 1000);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Покажите хоть что нибудь! Как приходит событие 3х, где нужна линия?

Comment: добвил код который проверяет кто победил

Comment: Как я понимаю, линию надо нарисовать на UI по тем 3х? Если так, то покажите, как вы рисуете поле 3х3. Предположу, что надо создать стили для полосок( / - \ | ) и потом добавлять нужный к элементу

Comment: ну поле я нарисовал с помошью 9 кнопок который находяться в 1 div

Comment: Поменяйте теги в запросе, тут TypeScript нет. Добавьте html, css